# How to add OnClickListener for disabled spinner in android?

Tags: android, spinner, onclicklistener, toast

I have a spinner in android and disabled it using,

```
Spinner SPMenuItem = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SPMenuItem);
SPMenuItem.setAlpha(0.7f);
SPMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
```

I want to display the following toast message on click of this disabled spinner.

```
SPMenuItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"This is a readonly field",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
```

But I get the following exception on load,

[image]

I just want to display toast message to indicate the spinner is disabled. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you explain what is your expectations or how the spinner should behave or is spinner populated ?

Comment: Yes the spinner is populated and a default value is set

Comment: Well, did you follow the explicit exception instructions and try `setOnItemClickListener` instead ... ?

Comment: Yes but it is not serving the purpose with setEnabled false.. I need to show a toast message to indicate the spinner is displayed..